# Send email daily using `wp_mail`

Tags: email, wp-mail

I want to send email daily 12:54pm using `wp_mail` function,  but it send mail continuously.

Plz suggest what is wrong?

```
<?php $timeg = date( 'g:ia', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ));
$timem = '12:54pm';
if ($timem == $timeg) 
{

$to = 'abc@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Post Published by Author';
$headers = 'From: admin <admin@urdutahzeeb.com>' . "\r\n";  
$message = 'your';

   wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

?>
```

Comment: are you sure that you call this code everyday at 12:54pm ?

Comment: Don't try to match the exact time using php only. It's inefficient and will cost you too much resources to accomplish Instead you should set up a cronjob. See threads like http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73627/how-to-make-cron-run-once-at-specific-time-per-day and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48538/how-can-i-ensure-my-cronjob-will-run-at-specified-time for details

Comment: You're matching the minute only, so every time the code is run that minute it'll send, not just the first time. So (depending where you put this) I'd guess that's why you see it sending mail continuously. But as others have said a scheduled job is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would explore the use of scheduled events in WorPdress, known as [wp-cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron).

Here is a example for that (not tested, just written here as proof of concept):

```
// 1.- Register custom escheduled event on plugin activiation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_plugin_activation' );
function cyb_plugin_activation() {

    if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cyb_daily_cron_job' ) ) {

        // Set first run time to today at 12:54 (or tomorrow at that time)
        $first_run_time = new DateTime( '12:54', new DateTimeZone( get_option( 'timezone_string' ) ) );
        $current_time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone( get_option( 'timezone_string' ) ) );

        if( $current_time->getTimestamp() > $first_run_time->getTimestamp() ){

            $first_run_time->modify('+1 day');

        }

        wp_schedule_event( first_run_time->getTimestamp(), 'daily', 'cyb_daily_cron_job' );

    }

}

// 2.- Hook a function to our scheduled event
add_action( 'cyb_daily_cron_job', 'cyb_send_daily_mail' );
function cyb_send_daily_mail() {

    $to = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Post Published by Author';
    $headers = 'From: admin <admin@urdutahzeeb.com>' . "\r\n";  
    $message = 'your';

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

// 3.- Remove custom escheduled event on plugin deactiviation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_plugin_deactivation' );
function cyb_plugin_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'cyb_daily_cron_job' );
}
```